# Can Safari on iOS be made to respect the "Text Size" control in Control Center?

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

Currently, if I use the [Text Size control in Control Center](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/display-text-size-iph3e2e1fb0/ios#:%7E:text=Adjust%20the%20text%20size%20when%20you%27re%20using%20an%20app&text=%2C%20add%20it%20to%20Control%20Center,or%20decrease%20the%20text%20size.) to change the size of text in iOS, web pages rendered by Safari do not seem to be rescaled.

Is there a way to make Safari's scaling/sizing behavior follow the Text Size setting?

Comment: Hmmmmm... I don't use the text size control as I have set it to a readable level that I find comfortable. Safari may not respect that, as websites can change fonts and sizes at will. But if you tap on the "AA" icon in Safari you can adjust the font size currently displayed, does that not work for you?

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes, you can do that (and I do). But that's a separate topic :-). I'm specifically trying to understand if Safari/WebKit can be made to respect the Text Size setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Website authors can choose to use the Dynamic Type text size using the `-apple-system-body` CSS font property value.

You can therefore use an extension to apply this to all fonts on all websites. For example, [Makeover](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/makeover-custom-css/id1602361167) is a Safari extension available on iOS that lets you apply custom CSS.

Use the following CSS to change all elements' font:

```css
* { font: -apple-system-body !important; }
```

All text will now use this font and respect Dynamic Type text size. Keep in mind this may break the layout of some websites.

Without an extension, Safari respects the Dynamic Type text size for its UI but does not apply this to websites.

Safari on macOS has its own option:
Preferences → Advanced → Accessibility: Never use font sizes smaller than *n*.

Safari on iOS does not have an equivalent option built in at present.
You can provide feedback to Apple at https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html.

Comment: This works! Thank you. The setting unfortunately affects the font family, weights and styles on all elements, but it's possible to set family/weight/etc separately and still have the resizing work. This page explains more: https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/mobile-a11y-tf/wiki/Specifying_a_system_font_in_web_content_to_support_platform_text_resize_without_browser_or_platform_assistive_technology_zoom.